# Adding Foreign Keys in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I guys,

I have two tables like this:

**"_config" table:**

[image]

---

**"_usuarios" table:**

[image]
And when i try to add a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `_config` ADD CONSTRAINT `_config__entitycreateuser_fk` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`_EntityCreateUser`) 
    REFERENCES `_usuarios`(`UsuarioId`) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE SET NULL
```

I receive this error:

> SQL Error (1005): Can't create table 'databasename'.'#sql-14a4_3'
>   (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update)

I try setting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS to 0 but returns:

> SQL Error (1825) Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table
>   '_config'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'databasename/_config__entitycreateuser_fk'
>   º
>   All tables are empty

Answer (score 3):

Check that the name for your foreign key is unique for the database

```
SELECT 
  constraint_name,
  table_name
FROM 
  information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE 
  constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
  AND table_schema = DATABASE()
  AND constraint_name = '_config__entitycreateuser_fk'
```

That's one of the most common fixes.

Open search version.

```
SELECT 
  constraint_name,
  table_name
FROM 
  information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE 
  constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
  AND table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY constraint_name ASC
```

In response to your comment, I am editing my answer once again.

Double check that the tables in question, `_config` and `_usuarios` are not partitioned. InnoDB has limitations on `FK` constraints for partitioned tables. You should be able to read up on specifics in the manual.

On a more useful note, try to run this `SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS` after attempting to add the `FK` constraint again. It will show you details of the error.

My guess now is that your issue is `...ON UPDATE SET NULL`. Since you would be trying to `SET NULL` on the `_usuarios.UsuarioId` column which appears to be an `IDENTITY` on your table. Being an `IDENTITY` automatically sets the column to `NOT NULLABLE`

Comment: Not found. 0 results

Comment: I posted an open search version in my answer. Just make sure it's not on that list either. Are you using linked databases by any chance?

Comment: they are innodb tables and the queries do not extract results